# Using "this" with jQuery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul class="faq">
    <li class="open">
        <a class="question" href="">This is my question?</a>
        <p>Of course you can, it will be awesome. </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using CSS I'm setting the `p` tag to `display:none;`. I want to use jQuery to display or hide the `p` tag when the `anchor` is clicked, but I'm having some troubles with the sibling selector.

Just trying to get the selector working, I tried:

```
$("a.question").click(function () {
    $(this + " ~ p").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

to test it out. Seemingly, the sibling selector can't really be used like that, and as I'm completely new to jQuery I don't know the appropriate means to make that happen.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using:

```
$(this).siblings('p').css()
```

Comment: Sweet, this is perfect (and much faster than a rather fruitless Google search). Thanks!

Comment: lazyweb is great isn't it? :) Oh and keep in mind that it will do that to _every_ 'p' tag in your <li> if you add more.

Comment: Not bitter?  Don't worry, my comment isn't constructive.

Comment: (5 years later...) To make it up to you Ben, I signed up for NSScreencasts about 6 months ago and have gotten quite a lot of it ;-).

Answer (score 14):

```
$(this).next("p").css("...")
```

the "p" above is optional, if you just want the next non-whitespace node in the DOM.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to use jQuery to display or hide the 'p' tag when the anchor is clicked

Since you mentioned that you'd like to toggle the 'p' tag when the anchor is clicked, I'd do:

```
  $("a.question").click(function (event) {
      $(this).siblings('p').show(); //toggle the p tags that are siblings to the clicked element
      event.preventDefault(); //stop the browser from following the link
  });
```

Comment: Ah, I had been wondering what the jQuery version of consuming a click event was. Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks, that saved me having to think further! I ended up going with slideToggle() instead of show() though, mostly because I want people to think I'm cool. ;)